# setting up user_id for Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I followed the directions given when setting up the User-ID option.

I then created a view named 'user_id' for showing user_id info, but I am not seeing anything.  When enabling User-ID, the code said to add the following to my tracking code.

```
gtag('set', {'user_id': '12345UserIdHere'});
```

However, when I go to the 'user_id' view, nothing is shown.

My current goal is to view which user ids were browsing the system during a given period of time.

Edit:
I am using this library:
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=MY-ID-STUFF

Comment: make sure you're using gtag.js and not gtm or analytics.js

Comment: @XTOTHEL: I believe I am using that code. I edited the post with the url I am using.

Answer (score 2):

I mostly used GTM, so I am not completely familiar with the gtag.js syntax, but I don't believe it has a "set" method. [According to the documentation you'd have to set the user id in the "config" call instead](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cookies-user-id#set_user_id):

```
gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', {
  'user_id': 'USER_ID'
});
```

(Things in caps are placeholders).

Comment: Yes, I confirm it.